# Solr faceting is splitting the single field into two using colon(:)

Tags: split, solr

I am running default query which gives all results with ':' because I want to get all records.

My field in Solr is like this- "host": "xyz.com:443" in all the documents.
So the faceting query on "host" field should return single value

host(the faceting field)-"xyz.com:443"(The value), 6487584(The number of records)

But instead it is returning two values

host(the faceting field)-
1."443"(The value), 5012877(The number of records)
2."xyz.com"(The value), 5012877(The number of records)

Why is it splitting the faceting field with ":" ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix is putting facet value in a StrField instead of TextField. Or use a seperate TextField with minimal analysis in schema.xml.